# Playing with z-index

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

Please enter [to this website](http://ecruting.tisoft.me/). (I can't recreate same problem on jsFiddle. Sorry) The problem is, when you press recommend's dropdown button, it changes parent div's height. How can I set dropdown menus position over the parent divs border? And why dropdown menu shows fonts white?

[image]

Comment: When you fix your issue on your website, how usefull this question will be without a code?

Answer (score 1):

Your "Recomend" button is not actually a dropdown menu, it's two buttons and an unordered list made to look like a dropdown menu. Therefore it won't function and display like a regular dropdown menu would i.e. overlay on top of the UI when you click it.

You will have to `position: absolute` the list underneath your buttons to achieve this affect.

---

UPDATE:

The problem is that the container your buttons are in is positioned relative, which changes the behavior of the child element positioning.

1. Remove `position: relative` from `.btn-group` and `#main`
2. Remove `left: 0` and `top: 100%` from `.dropdown-menu`

Comment: where to set position: absolute ? which selector, class, id?

Comment: Looking into your code some more you are positioning it absolutely, the problem is that the container that your buttons are in is positioned relative. To fix: remove `position: relative` from `.btn-group` and `#main`, and remove `left: 0` and `top: 100%` from `.dropdown-menu`.

Answer (score 1):

change css for class `dropdown-menu` to `position: relative`

the color of class `dropdown-menu a` is getting overwritten by `#topContainer a`

you can inspect elements using developer tools of the browser.

Comment: please rate & accept the answer that works for you, gives the poster some points :)